# Large image, maintain size of content on right

Tags: php, html, css

I have two sizes of images (vertical and horizontal), they will always be the same size, respectfully. I am trying to create a container that would hold the image but not push the content over and stay a similar height or width.  I also dont want to show the image full size so I was thinking about using `overflow:hidden`. I have attempted this in a JSFiddle seen here but it stretches the container. Any help is appreciated.

```
<div>
  <span class="mixSpanLeft">
    <a href="somePlace.html"><img src="http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/26/79/HoFC0h.jpg" /></a>
  </span>
  <span class="mixSpanRight">
    <p>The images will always be on the left and will be only two sizes, 1000x500 or 500x1000. What is the best way to show them if they have alternating sizes?  Should I have completely different styles for them?
    </p>
  </span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hmjoLmej/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this.

I used the more appropriate `flexbox` instead of `float`, which gives greater control of the layout.

The image is added using `background`, which gives greater control to scale, clip, etc.

*Note, since the `p` is block element they should not be children of a `span` (which is inline element), so I updated your markup/CSS with a `div`*

***Updated**, showing how you can add the image source in the markup*

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.mixSpanLeft {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #abc;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: cover;
}

.mixSpanLeft a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mixDivRight {
  width: 50%;
  background: #def;
}

.mixDivRight p {
  padding: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="mixSpanLeft" style="background-image: url(http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/26/79/HoFC0h.jpg)">
  <a href="somePlace.html"></a>
  </span>
  <div class="mixDivRight">
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="mixSpanLeft" style="background-image: url(http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/29/20/3HE5Mx.jpg)">
  <a href="somePlace.html"></a>
  </span>
  <div class="mixDivRight">
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks LGSon!  This is exactly what I was trying to explain... however, is there any way to do this or similar but not using a background image? There will be multiples of these on a page and can't use an image in the CSS.

Comment: @CoolShape Since there is no really good way to do this using `img`, I updated my answer showing how you can add the image source in the markup

Comment: Ahhh duh! That makes sense.  So you are still setting it but just "inline".  I like this.  Thanks a ton!  I need to re-read about elements.

Comment: @CoolShape You're welcome, and for the `img` there is the [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property, which can do similar, though it have less browser support

Comment: Looks like no IE support for object-fit.  geez IE!

Comment: @CoolShape Is my answer good enough to be upvoted/accepted? .. If not, let me know how I can improve it

Comment: Ooops sorry @LGSon.  Yeah it works... Been trying to make it better myself because if there is no content in the right div or less then others the image is smaller or gets cut off.  If I use a set height or width it gets wonky.  Thanks!   Also trying to use some jquery to find the linkage in the left area but I am going to have to post that as a new question.

Comment: @CoolShape So you retracted your accept, what went wrong?

Comment: Sorry that was an accident but yeah I am still trying to get your solution to work with vertical images without having to write more CSS.  http://jsfiddle.net/5s9b8xmh/   Maybe I didnt explain it very well.